# Jquery , touch event, how to scrolling object's offset top faster (speed rate)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used javascript touch event to change object's offset top. It can work like a scrolling move, but I want to scroll it speed rate faster,( ex: Double/triple speed ), how do I do for the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <style>
      .box{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #111;
      }
    </style>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var $window = $(window);
        var $box = $('.box');
        var objOffsetX;
        var moveOffsetX;
        $window.on('touchstart', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var touch = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
          objOffsetX = $box.offset().top;
          moveOffsetX = objOffsetX - touch.pageY;
        });
        $window.on('touchmove', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var touch = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
          var positionX = touch.pageY + moveOffsetX ;
          $box.offset({top:positionX});
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure I get it right. Is this what you meant: `var positionX = touch.pageY * 2 + moveOffsetX ;`?

Comment: I tried this code, the speed rate was faster, but when I touch start at the different position, the box object's position jumped to another position, it has a bug.

Comment: Maybe try adding var i = 0; below var moveOffsetX; and add i++ inside 'touchstart' function then var positionX = touch.pageY + moveOffsetX + i;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery , touch event, how to scrolling object's offset top faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219309/jquery-touch-event-how-to-scrolling-objects-offset-top-faster)

Comment: Thanks for Mark's answer, I tried this code, but it still not work, the box speed rate was still the same with mouse, It just plus 1px at every time I touch start.

Comment: OK, Thanks for Michael's remind, I was already delete the repeat question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animate

```
  $("HTML, BODY").animate({ scrollTop: positionX }, 1000); }); });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to move the $('.box') by touch event, and the speed rate faster, not the HTML scroll animate faster.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from what I understood, my assumption was correct, but there was an issue when you starting drag in a different point.
Here is what you need:

```js
$(function () {
        // set here your needed speed multiplier.
        // 1 means it will follow your move with same speed.
        var multiplier = 2;
        var $window = $(window);
        var $box = $('.box');
        var objOffsetX;
        var moveOffsetX;
        var initialPageY;
        $window.on('touchstart', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var touch = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
          objOffsetX = $box.offset().top;
          moveOffsetX = objOffsetX - touch.pageY;
          initialPageY = touch.pageY;
        });
        $window.on('touchmove', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var touch = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
          var positionX = touch.pageY * multiplier - initialPageY * (multiplier - 1) + moveOffsetX ;
          $box.offset({top:positionX});
        });
      });
```

```css
.box{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #111;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </body>
```